# need reference text in functional analysis

Tags: reference-request

Can you recommend me books in which i can learn functional analysis and understand material like weak convergence (with its topology) ?
what are also the first books written on the subject.
Is it Banach's book "operator theory" ?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't read either of these, but I know that both Serge Lang's *Real and Functional Analysis* and Rudin's *Functional Analysis* cover weak convergence.

I don't know anything about the history of the subject, but Rudin gives a brief discussion on the importance of Banach's work in the appendix of his text.